# function fitting over a sparse grid using Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, sparse-matrix

I am looking for a Python piece of code for function fitting over a multi-dimensional sparse grid. I'm rather interested in polynomial fitting.

To be more specific, a sparse grid data is far less in number compared to the full grid data, so that maybe we would have available too less than required function values in order to become able to find all the coefficients of a multi-dimensional polynomial fitting the sparse grid data. Any idea better than to first use the sub-package "griddata" to interpolate the sparse grid data on the full grid data then polynomial fitting of the data? Any Python code already available for that?

Comment: f_discret[i,j,k] = f(x[i], y[j], z[k]), no?

Comment: @RomanFursenko, I couldn't find anything about "_discret[]" inside the web for Python, does this find a continuous function that fit to data already known on a sparse grid? If yes can you please clarify more?

Comment: sorry, before editing I did not understand your question correct. So, please ignore my previous comment. Now I understand your question, but I can not propose more than solution you already mention in your question.

Comment: I put my answer here: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19137

Comment: @denfromufa, thanks for your information, I read your topic and it seems quite informative, right now but I have no problem at hand for which to try them, my previous problem is left unsolved but I am trying Galerkin Approximation instead to solve it.